# Python error: I install it correctly but still doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I tried to import the following code in python, but an error message occurred.
I am using Python 3.6.4, Windows

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Error message:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Actually I did install the following code in CMD:

```
pip install keras
pip install Sequential
```

Could anyone tell me what else should I install or how should I do? Thank you.

Comment: `pip install tensorflow`? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

Comment: doesn't work at cmd, error msg: Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: Install tensorflow directly from wheel file, not from pip. You can find tensorflow wheel files for windows here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow - pay attention you are downloading the version matching your python version

Comment: Hi, bluesummers, how can I install .whl in win10?

Comment: I downloaded tensorflow‑1.4.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win, I am not sure does it match my python 3.6.4

Comment: working with `python 3.6` the requirments are `Keras==2.1.2` , `tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0`. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Keras has a default backend of Tensorflow. So first install the tensorflow with the command, 
`pip install tensorflow` 
You can do this in your current stage too. It should work fine.

Comment: error msg: Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: Thats an error from pip. Update your pip. If it still doesn't work, install Tensorflow from source.. There will be a lot of warnings but it'll work.